# How to show someting when the post finish? jQuery

Tags: jquery

I create Recommended Content Box or Check Also, on the corner of screen, When someone scroll down the box is show, But I want this box show when someone scroll down until the post finished?
My Code :

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        jQuery('.recommended-content').css({
            right: "0"
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.recommended-content').css({
            right: "-400px"
        });
    }
});
```

My Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/31xd8b5x/21/

Comment: Change the if condition as below 

$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar Supe Thank you but can you tell what is the if condition that I can use?

Comment: wait, I will add this as answer

Comment: @MutamizTeam I added an answer before he said. Can you kindly check my fiddle and answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, can you please change the condition to:

```
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > jQuery(".post").height() - 650)
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xo90ct9x/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, That what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code so that when user approches the bottom of page your recommended post will become visible

```
 jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-100) {
         jQuery('.recommended-content').css({
             right: "0"
         });
     } else {
         jQuery('.recommended-content').css({
             right: "-400px"
         });
     } });
```

Comment: Thank you but with this code my recommended content is visible on footer, but this okay I found the best answer :)

Comment: @MutamizTeam I am sorry I did not understood, what do you mean by content is visible on footer? Is it not working?

Comment: I mean the recommended content is show when I scroll down until the footer, not when the post finished!